# Let $M_n = [k ∈ N : k = nm$ for some integer $m > 1]$. What is $∪_{n∈N}M_n$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

This was a problem I was marked off for on a homework assignment, and I'd like to know if what I did was just the way I wrote my answer or if the idea behind the answer is wrong as well.

I plugged in a few values for $n$ to see what sets I would get.

$M_1 = [k ∈ N : k = m]$

So, because $m > 1$, $k$ must also be $>1$, so $k$ is $(1, ∞)$.

$M_2 = [k ∈ N : k = 2m]$

So $k > 2$, which makes it $(2, ∞)$.

Since it's clear the set gets smaller for increasing values of $n$, the union of the sets is $(1, ∞)$.

The reason the answer was marked incorrect was that this set contains non-integers. So, would this answer be valid if I were to change it to $[2, ∞) ∈ N$?

Comment: You should only be getting *integers* in your set; that's what the $N$ means. $M_1 = \{2,3,4,\cdots \}$ (not $(1,\infty)$), $M_2 = \{ 4, 6, 8, \cdots \}$, etc. The union will be $\{2,3,4, \cdots\}$; I'm not sure whether your instructor would consider $[2,\infty)$ to be the same thing. (Interval notation usually means you're working with real numbers.)

Comment: $M_1 = (2,\infty) \cap \mathbb{N} =\{2,3, \ldots \}$

Comment: @user1952009 : $2\not\in (2,\infty)$.

Comment: Ok, so it seems like I may have just phrased my answer incorrectly. Considering his comment, it sounds like he doesn't accept the interval as the same thing.